# Error 1050 on Webhook PATCH

Tags: curl, surveymonkey

I'm trying to `PATCH` my existing webhook (edited `webhook_id`, and all `object_ids` for privacy as well as `ACCESS_TOKEN`, they are all correct in the `curl`. When I submit it I get this error:

> {"error": {"docs": "https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#error-codes", "message": "Oh bananas!  We couldn't process your request.", "id": "1050", "name": "Internal Server Error", "http_status_code": 500}}

And here's my request (I also tried `curl --request PATCH`):

```
curl -X PATCH 
-H "Authorization:bearer ACCESS_TOKEN" 
-H "Content-Type":"application/json" 
https://api.surveymonkey.net/v3/webhooks/{id} -d \ 
    '{
        "object_type":"survey", 
        "object_ids":["123","456","789"]
    }'
```

I included `object_type` because without it it was throwing an error that said it couldn't find a `collector` with that ID. I can probably just delete the webhook and recreate it but it's pretty annoying I can't just get the PATCH to work.

edit: running this in terminal and when I do I don't have the same spacing, I did that for readability

Comment: I deleted the webhook and posted a new one with the object id I was trying to add and it submitted fine. I will need to PATCH it again to change the `subscription_url` or just delete again but that's a hassle to do every time

Comment: that's a bug, should be fixed soon. If not contact SurveyMonkey support

Comment: thanks for info @GeneralKandalaft